# How to sort an array on a file created with IO?

Tags: java, arrays, input, io, output

Problem: "(Write/Read data) Write a program to create a file named Excercise 12_15 if it does not exist. Write 100 integers created randomly into the file using text I/o. Integers are seperated by spaces in the file. Read the data back from the file and display the data in ascending order"

This is what I have tried, but I'm not sure of what to do or revise from this point:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class SortedArrayIO {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        java.io.File file = new java.io.File("arrays.text");
        if (file.exists()) {
            System.out.println("File already exists");
            System.exit(1);
        }


    java.io.PrintWriter output = new java.io.PrintWriter(file);

    int[] array = new int[100];
    Random random = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = random.nextInt(100) + 1;
    }


    Arrays.sort(array);
    output.print(Arrays.toString(array));
}
}
```

Comment: Well what's the desired result compared with the actual result? You appear to already be sorting the result - my guess is that the only problem is the format... which has nothing to do with the format, or even that you're writing to a file. (You can do the same thing writing to a console.) Hint: you don't have to do it all in one `print` statement...

Comment: Please edit the post to include a description of the problem. Why does this need revising?

Comment: For those who have responded, I have put the actual problem, if that caused confusion. And by the way Jon, I think I know what you're saying, but I don't.

Comment: I notice no matter what I change, I always get an error that says "Cannot find symbol - class IOException"

Comment: @Johnny That's a compile-time error, import `java.io.IOException`.

Comment: @Bubletan after doing so, I recieved this error "Cannot find symbol - variable Arrays". It is referring to "Arrays" in Arrays.sort(array);

Comment: @Johnny Import it too: `java.util.Arrays`

Comment: @Bubletan Thank you so much. The last question may be minor or major. It doesn't have syntax errors now, but the text document is blank?

Comment: @Bubletan could this result be because the toString is not a function that I have defined?

Comment: @Johnny The `toString` method from `Arrays` is completely fine, but I don't know if `PrintWriter` flushes automatically. Try calling `output.flush()` at the end.

Comment: @Bubletan That's a cool method. My program finally works. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @Johnny: please do not add "Solved" to your title. There is a correct procedure to indicate this. Perhaps you should have taken the (short!) time to read the introductory [tour] when signing up.

Answer (score 0):

`Arrays.toString(array)` separates the values with `", "` and adds `"["` and `"]"` at the sides.

You can remove the unwanted symbols using `replaceAll`:

```
Arrays.toString(array).replaceAll("\\[|\\]|,", "")
```

Or you can create the `String` differently, e.g.:

```
Arrays.stream(array).mapToObj(Integer::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(" "))
```

Or also, you can print them one by one:

```
for (int i : array) {
    output.print(i + " ");
}
```

Comment: I'm going to try to revise with what you gave me